# Why is c not returning my string?

Tags: c, format, printf, stdout

I don't understand why the program below returns "z@" as string. But when I put a `printf("%s \n","");` before that, then it returns "11110111" (as aspected). 
Can anybody help me to understand this behaviour? 
Many thanks in advance!

Please find my whole program posted below:

```
#include <stdio.h>

char * bin2str(unsigned char bin) {
char str[] = "00000000";
int i;

    for (i=7; i>=0; i--) {

        if ((bin%2)==0) {
            str[i] = '0';   
        } else {
            str[i] = '1';   
        }
        bin = bin >> 1;

    }

    return ((char *) str);
}


int main() {
    unsigned char testChar;

    testChar |= 0b11110111;
    printf("Let us test binary to string: \n\n \n");

    //printf("%s \n","");
    printf("%s \n", bin2str(testChar)); //now it returns rubbish, but when the previous line is uncommented it turns out to be working correctly. Why?
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your `str` is local to `bin2str`. Once you exit from that function it doesn't exist anymore. Accessing it is undefined behavior, which means it may or may not work. It may also explode your computer. In short, you shouldn't use it and you shouldn't return a pointer to a local variable. The reason it sometimes works is that the string is kept on the stack. The reason it sometimes doesn't work is that another function (`printf`) overwrites that part of the stack.

Comment: @Shahbaz: Do you know examples of computers that exploded after undefined behavior?
But I understand that I corrupted my own string...

Comment: I know of many viruses in Windows. I'm not sure which is worse.

Comment: @Shahbaz Windows is worse than undefined behavior, because undefined behavior may sometimes "work".

Comment: @H2CO3, good one! (although I meant: "which is worse, having windows (infected, naturally) or having your computer exploded?")

Comment: @Shahbaz Of course ;) But I have a strong opinion about Windows, and as you can probably tell, it's not very positive :P

Comment: @H2CO3, you are my new friend on SO ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are generating a string as a local variable inside `bin2str()`. That string will be located in stack space while `bin2str()` is executing. As soon as the function returns, the stack space is no longer valid, and the memory pointed by str will contains whether the program puts in the stack between the return from the call to `bin2str()` and the call to `printf()` where you intend to print the contents of `str`.

Alternatives:

- Declare `str` as static. This way, `str` won't be placed in stack space and its contents will be available even after the function ends. Beware! as this solution is not thread safe.
- Change your prototype so it accepts a second argument, which will be the address of a string that the caller will have to provide, to which `bin2str()` will write the binary representation of the number.

Answer (score 4):

You are returning the local variable `str` from the function `bin2str` which is [*undefined behaviour*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). Instead you could copy it using [`strdup()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strdup.3.html) (or its equivalent using `malloc()` + `strcpy()`).

```
char *str = strdup("00000000");
```

and return it.

Don't forget to `free()` it!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks you all for your feedback. Wow, that was fast! 
It was my first post.

I made the changes. Please find the correct functioning program below (without compile warnings):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char * bin2str(unsigned char bin) {
    char *str = strdup("00000000");
    int i;

    for (i=7; i>=0; i--) {

        if ((bin%2)==0) {
            str[i] = '0';   
        } else {
            str[i] = '1';   
        }
        bin = bin >> 1;

    }

    return ((char *) str);
    free(str);

}


int main() {
    unsigned char testChar;

    testChar |= 0b11110111;
    printf("Let us test binary to string: \n\n \n");

    printf("%s \n", bin2str(testChar));
    return 0;
}
```